Trying to get input from dataframe and using values cell by cell to output into a text file
I have an excel sheet with data in following format



Bus num
Bus name
POI bus




20000
J874
0


20001
J976
0


10000
J1000
333333



I want to divide dataframe into two dataframes for value within POI bus column, hence one dataframe will have rows 1 and 2, and other will have row 3.
After this, I am trying to get data from both the dataframes using iloc function for all the rows, and specific columns. The code is working of dataframe 1 but not working for dataframe 2, and python is throwing  " raise KeyError(key) from err".
Code I am using:
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd

input_file = '..\Bench\Gen_addition_total.xlsx'

wb = load_workbook(input_file)
ws = wb.active
    
output_file1 = open('..\Bench\Gen_sub.inch','w')
output_file2 = open('..\Bench\Gen_tap.inch','w')

df0 = pd.read_excel(input_file)
df1 = df0[(df0['POI 2'] == 0)]
df2 = df0[(df0['POI 2'] != 0)]

def gen_sub():
    for i in range(len(df1)):
        bus_num = (df1.iloc[:,0])
        bus_name = (df1.iloc[:,1])
        n1 = bus_num[i]
        n2 = bus_name[i]
        output_file1.write(str(n1).strip("()"))+ output_file1.write('\n') + output_file1.write(str(n2).strip("()")) + output_file1.write('\n')
    output_file1.close()
    
def gen_tap():    
    for j in range(len(df2)):
        bus_num = (df2.iloc[:,0])
        bus_name = (df2.iloc[:,1])
        n4 = bus_num[j]
        n5 = POI_bus2[j]
        output_file2.write(str(n4).strip("()"))+ output_file2.write('\n') + output_file2.write(str(n5).strip("()")) + output_file2.write('\n')
    output_file2.close()
    
gen_sub()  
gen_tap()

When I run code for just gen_sub function, code is running perfectly, and I am getting following output:
20000
J874
20001
J976
But when I am trying to run code for both the functions I am getting error: "raise KeyError(key) from err"
When I run code for just gen_sub function, code is running perfectly, and I am getting following output:
20000
J874
20001
J976

But when I am trying to run code for both the functions I am getting error:
    in gen_tap
        n4 = bus_num[j]
    
      File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\pandas\core\series.py:1007 in __getitem__
        return self._get_value(key)
    
      File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\pandas\core\series.py:1116 in _get_value
        loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
    
      File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3655 in get_loc
        raise KeyError(key) from err
    
    KeyError: 0


Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

@MichaelButscher Made the changes as suggested by you. Do you have any input on possible issue in the line of code?

You are mixing access by integer position with access by label. Better use n4 = df2.iat[j, 0] and similarly for the other access operations.

One approach is to do this:
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Bus num': [20000, 20001, 10000],
    'Bus name': ['J874', 'J976', 'J1000'],
    'POI bus': [0, 0, 333333]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df1 = df[df['POI bus'] == 0]
df2 = df[df['POI bus'] != 0]

def gen_sub(output_file1, df1):
    with open(output_file1, 'w') as file:
        for i in range(len(df1)):
            bus_num = df1.iloc[i, 0]
            bus_name = df1.iloc[i, 1]
            file.write(f"{bus_num}\n")
            file.write(f"{bus_name}\n")

def gen_tap(output_file2, df2):
    with open(output_file2, 'w') as file:
        for j in range(len(df2)):
            bus_num = df2.iloc[j, 0]
            bus_name = df2.iloc[j, 1]
            poi_bus = df2.iloc[j, 2]
            file.write(f"{bus_num}\n")
            file.write(f"{bus_name}\n")
            file.write(f"{poi_bus}\n")

output_file1 = 'Gen_sub.inch'
output_file2 = 'Gen_tap.inch'

gen_sub(output_file1, df1)
gen_tap(output_file2, df2)

which gives you (in the .inch files)
Gen_sub
20000
J874
20001
J976

and Gen_tap
10000
J1000
333333


